# SQLalchemy rollback while catching exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a function similar to the below:

```
def data_to_sql(response: pd.DataFrame, table, engine, if_exists="append"):

    try:
       response.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists)
    except:
       sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError as e:
       data = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", con=engine)
       new_response = pd.concat([data, response])
       new_response.to_sql(table, con=engine, index=False,
                           if_exists="replace")
```

This exception occurs when there is an undefined column; when there is a column in the response (DataFrame) that is not in the table you are appending to in the database.

Now, I am calling this function within another function:

```
def another_function(response, table, engine, if_exists="append"):
    # extract data from response here which gives us 3
    # different responses which we want to append to different tables

    with engine.begin() as con:
      data_to_sql(response1, table=table+"1", engine=con, if_exists=if_exists)

      data_to_sql(response2, table=table+"2", engine=con, if_exists=if_exists)  

      data_to_sql(response3, table=table+"3", engine=con, if_exists=if_exists)
```

Now, the `engine.begin()` ensures that whenever an error occurs within this, the changes are rolled back to its previous state.

Now, this isn't working as I'm expecting. The `response2` is what is causing the exception in the `data_to_sql()` function, and whenever I handle this exception (`sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError`),
the `table2`is updated with the new data (through the handling of the exception), but neither `table1` not `table3` are and I get an error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This transaction is inactive`.

This seems like something to do with rollback scope or terminating the session before the commit or something along them lines, but I can't figure it out.